# Description in UWP ComboBox

Tags: user-interface, uwp, combobox, controls

I'm trying to get a combobox (or equivalent) to include a short description of the option in the dropdown as well as the title, as shown in this quick doodle I did:
[dropdown doodle that I can't embed in question, sorry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY4hy.jpg)

I have tried googling for an option, but I didn't have much luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Luca Lindholm said, you need to cunstomize the `ComboBox.ItemTemplate`.
You can see the result.

[image]

Xaml code:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="combo" Width=" 200" Margin="20 0 0 0" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:UserSS">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind option}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind option_desc}" Margin="20 0 0 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

cs code:

```
    List<UserSS> list = new List<UserSS>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        UserSS user = new UserSS
        {
            option = "Option" + i.ToString(),
            option_desc = "Desc" + i.ToString()
        };
        list.Add(user);
    }
    combo.ItemsSource = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can choose to customize the *ItemTemplate* of the `ComboBox`, and by:

- Creating a ViewModel for the object and a main ViewModel for the app...
- Creating a `DataTemplate` and setting it as the *ItemTemplate*
  of the `ComboBox`...
- Using a `ObservableCollection` with your object ViewModel, in the main ViewModel, as an *ItemsSource* for your `ComboBox`...
- and finally data binding the XAML inside the `DataTemplate` to the properties of the object viewmodel...

...you should be fine.

Regards